# Extending a dryer cord: which method is safest?

Tags: electrical, dryer, appliances, stacked-washer-dryer

I recently stacked my clothes dryer on top of my washer and the cable of my dryer is now too short to reach its outlet. I'd like to extend the cable so that it can. Swapping the cord for a longer one isn't an option because the dryer uses a proprietary cable that's only available in one length. The dryer and cable are the same as the ones in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282326/are-dryer-extension-cords-legal-and-safe). For reasons of hassle and expense, I want to avoid moving the outlet.

I only need an extra foot of two of cord, so I'd ideally like to purchase a short extension cord. Unfortunately, short dryer extension cords (1-2 feet) don't seem to exist.

Searching on Amazon and online, I can see three options. My question is, which of these is safest, and why?

1. Buying a 10-foot extension cord (such as [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Extension-Canada-Charging-14-30P-14-30R)). This length seems to be the most readily available, but this solution would involve having many feet of excess cable coiled behind the dryer.
2. Making my own short extension cord, using [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/100993/5806) or [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/100994/5806) as a guide.
3. Buying a 3-foot Y-splitter (such as [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Splitter-Receptacle-Welding-Connector-Connecter/dp/B09898BD55/)). I'd only be using one end of the Y; no second appliance would ever be plugged in. Despite involving an extra unused female connector, I feel better about this solution because it involves less cable. (is this feeling justified?)

How might these three solutions be ranked in terms of their safety and/or legality, and what would be the reasons for the rankings?

Also, comments have suggested swapping the dryer cord for a longer one. Though not possible in this case, in principle why would this approach be safer than using an extension cord?

Comment: Is this a 100 percent electric dryer (no gas)?

Comment: Yes. 100% electric.

Comment: Any competent electrician can replace the existing cored with a longer one - perfectly safe.

Comment: Just asking is this a new dryer that would be in the return period or an older dryer?

Comment: @SolarMike swapping the cord isn't possible. See edits

Comment: @crip659 we've had the dryer for several years. It can't be returned. The problem has arisen because we recently stacked it on top of the washer. See edits.

Comment: Swapping the cord is possible - see "competent electrician". Also, if you don't have the skills to swap the cord then I suggest you don't have the skills to make an extension.

Comment: I'm perfectly comfortable with the mechanics of swapping the cord. The issue is that this model of dryer (LG DLE3500W) uses a proprietary cable that's only made in one length. Standard dryer cables can't be used because they end in moulded ring terminals, which can't be attached to the machine. If you can direct me to a website that sells a longer version of the cable for the LG DLE3500W I'd be grateful and more than happy to swap it.

Comment: @SolarMike I've edited the question to ask why replacing the existing cord with a longer one would be any safer than using an extension cord. If you can explain this to me all my up votes will be yours :)

Comment: I've got it.   Stack the washer on top...but not directly (not allowed).  Build a shelf/table capable of holding the weight and vibration of a washer.  Strap the washer to it.  With the dryer on the bottom, the cord should reach.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [owner's manual for the LG DLE3500W dryer](https://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=VwRccFXQDqbn3LdkQ1YpA)

> Do not use an extension cord or adapter with this appliance.

If the extension cord starts a fire, your insurance company will very likely not pay your claim, and you'd be out a house but still owe the mortgage for it.

Per an answer by @Jack on @SolarMike's linked question https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/282331/140350

> Many codes do not allow extension cords for permanent installation.

Jack also highlights the manufacturer restriction on using extension cords.

The 3-foot Y-splitter you linked to does not appear to have a UL or equivalent safety mark, so it is even more a concern if it is used.

The only safe method to extend your dryer power, if you cannot get a longer cord for the dryer, even from LG, is to move the dryer outlet. A surface-mount electrical box extender, a few feet of conduit, a surface-mount electric box and a few feet of correct-gauge wire & wire nuts should be relatively inexpensive compared to no insurance coverage. (If you live in an apartment or a particularly restrictive jurisdiction, you may have to get an electrician. But an new question on how to wire and assemble this yourself if you're allowed to may save some money and be pretty easy too.)

If 'not moving the outlet' is an absolute, then unstacking the dryer and putting it back where it was is the safest.

Comment: I'm new to this. I assumed that moving the outlet would imply cutting into bathroom tiles and drywall. When you mention a "surface mount electrical box extender", do you mean that the box could be moved without cutting into the wall?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Try web-searching "surface mount box extender", you'll see electric boxes with no back, which cap onto in-wall boxes. This brings the electricity out on the surface of the wall instead of within the wall. Then conduit and a new box, with the old outlet and cover, and your outlet is moved. You'd still need to drill mounting screws into the wall, but no cutting of huge holes.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the original cord with a longer cord will be safer because:

1. there will be no extra connections that can become loose and over heat,
2. the new cord can be of a cable grade the same, or better, than the original - both in terms of conductor and insulation/protection.
3. many extension cords might look good - as in thick but the thickness often comes form insulation and the conductors are minimally sized. Then the terminals are "softer" and easily bend, often when used to the maximum rating they overheat easily. Had experience of "cheap" extensions - now I either buy good ones or make my own.

Comment: LG has made this option close to impossible for normal electrical DIY.  They use special plugs so replacing with a longer or non expensive LG cord is hard, almost means a splice.

Comment: Your points imply that a high quality extension cord, with good conductor and insulation, with connections that are not loose, would be perfectly safe. Is this the case?